# Can a man have sex with wife if bleeding continues even after the exact time of women monthly bleeding?

Tags: sex, husband-wife, menses

If a woman miscarries after two months, then the 40 days of women bleeding finishes and then the monthly bleeding starts and then its time finishes as well, but still the bleeding continues, in this case can her husband have sex with her or not?
Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 0):

for monthly  bleeding (menstruation ), some scholars say that the bleeding after 15 days is considered (istihada) , which is vaginal bleeding other than menstruation , or what is called " intermenstrual bleeding" .  and most scholars say you can have intercourse during it , and some say you cannot ,.... https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/2278